Failed to fetch file gs://chromium-clang-format/025ca7c75f37ef4a40f3a67d81ddd11d7d0cdb9b - Error while executing "gclient sync"
I am working on a remote machine to set up the release build for my application. We have depot_tools dependencies, so while executing the gclient sync command, we are facing some Python-related issues.
Logs are given below.
########### Building LIVE branch ############
build.py:34: DeprecationWarning: Use shutil.which instead of find_executable
qmake_path = find_executable( "qmake" )
util.check_call_debug: invoking "./libs/build_mac.sh" "/usr/local/Qt-5.15.15/bin/qmake" "release" in directory /Users/temp/Documents/latest_application/develop
---> building with /usr/local/Qt-5.15.15/bin/qmake -config release
using libc++
--> building crashpad
Syncing projects: 100% (11/11), done.

________ running 'download_from_google_storage --no_resume --no_auth --bucket=chromium-clang-format --sha1_file buildtools/mac/clang-format.sha1' in '/Users/temp/Documents/latest_application/develop/libs'
0> Downloading buildtools/mac/clang-format@025ca7c75f37ef4a40f3a67d81ddd11d7d0cdb9b...
0> Failed to fetch file gs://chromium-clang-format/025ca7c75f37ef4a40f3a67d81ddd11d7d0cdb9b for buildtools/mac/clang-format, skipping. [Err: Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = '/Users/temp/Library/Caches/.vpython-root/store/python_venv-qibdebubh7qlh677024rqqkj9s/contents/bin/python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 0
  safe_path = 0
  import site = 1
  is in build tree = 0
  stdlib dir = '/opt/s/w/ir/x/w/3pp/wd/tools/cpython3/mac-amd64/3.11.8/out/lib/python3.11'
  sys._base_executable = '/Users/temp/Library/Caches/.vpython-root/store/python_venv-qibdebubh7qlh677024rqqkj9s/contents/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = '/opt/s/w/ir/x/w/3pp/wd/tools/cpython3/mac-amd64/3.11.8/out'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/opt/s/w/ir/x/w/3pp/wd/tools/cpython3/mac-amd64/3.11.8/out'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = '/opt/s/w/ir/x/w/3pp/wd/tools/cpython3/mac-amd64/3.11.8/out'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/opt/s/w/ir/x/w/3pp/wd/tools/cpython3/mac-amd64/3.11.8/out'
  sys.path = [
    '/opt/s/w/ir/x/w/3pp/wd/tools/cpython3/mac-amd64/3.11.8/out/lib/python311.zip',
    '/opt/s/w/ir/x/w/3pp/wd/tools/cpython3/mac-amd64/3.11.8/out/lib/python3.11',
    '/opt/s/w/ir/x/w/3pp/wd/tools/cpython3/mac-amd64/3.11.8/out/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x000000010ab84dc0 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>

Python issues: The logs show Python-related problems, but lack details. We have tried different Python versions (3.11, 3.8), adjusted PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH, and checked various resources, but the build still fails.  
The main issue is "Python not finding the encodings module, which is crucial for the setup".
Any ideas?
I have already gone through this Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding, when trying to start uwsgi
I have tried every step from the solution that suggested above
Ex - Check Python Configuration:
Ensure Proper File Permissions:
Reinstall Python or Use Virtual Environments
Created new virtual environment
Unset the PYTHONHOME,PYTHONPATH 
set different PYTHONHOME,PYTHONPATH
Difference in the question are :
In my issue stdlib dir, sys.prefix, sys.exec_prefix, sys.path are /opt/s/w/ir/x/w/3pp/wd/tools/cpython3 which does not even exist in the system.
program name = '/Users/temp/Library/Caches/.vpython-root/store/python_venv-qibdebubh7qlh677024rqqkj9s/contents/bin/python3' is there but in /Users/temp/Library/Caches/.vpython-root/store/python_venv-qibdebubh7qlh677024rqqkj9s/contents/lib/python3.11/site-packages it does not have encoding which causes issue, whenever we run the "gclient sync" uses same path internally in depot_tool.

@AlexKulinkovich please don't reopen and approve clear duplicate questions from the Staging Ground just because you fixed some formatting or removed noise from the post.
